# OpenLayers2 Mobile add marker

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to display some markers on Openlayers map mobile version. I know that standard way of adding markers on Openlayers does not work with Openlayers mobile library. The example of Openlayers site didn't help me add a marker dynamically. Can somebody show me the correct way of implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I was reading and it seems that there are no makers in Open Layers mobile. So the solutions is to make a feature with a point inside.
Here is an example of how I did it.

```
/** function that is used to join a point to the map*/
function agregarPunto(long, lat, ZoomLevel){
    var proyeccion = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(longitud, latitud)
    .transform(proyeccion , // transform from WGS 1984
      map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    );
    var punto = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonLat.lon, lonLat.lat);
    vector.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(punto,{},styleCross)]);
    map.setCenter(lonLat, ZoomLevel, false, false);
}
```